# Clearing the console in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

I want to clear console by entering '0' in the 'istep' or 'ito' but in only works when I enter '0' in the 'ito'...can somebody fix this and explain what is the reason of this behavior?THANKS!

```
import os

while True:
   ifrom=int(input("From: "))
   istep=int(input("Step: "))
   ito=int(input("To: "))

   if istep==0 or ito==0:
       os.system('cls')
```

Comment: Are you on Linux or WIndows?

Comment: @Cardstdani Hey, I'm using 'Windows 10'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use several `if` conditions, as `ito` only gets a value after user inputs something for `istep`:

```
import os

while True:
   ifrom=int(input("From: "))
   istep=int(input("Step: "))
   if istep==0:
       os.system('cls')
   ito=int(input("To: "))

   if ito==0:
       os.system('cls')
```

Comment: the OP was already using the == on both conditions

Answer (score 1):

simplier solution to use a list of values for if-statement

```py
import os

while True:
   ifrom=int(input("From: "))
   istep=int(input("Step: "))
   ito=int(input("To: "))
   if 0 in [istep, ito]:
       os.system('cls')
```

Comment: This is very inintuitive, doesn't `if 0 in [istep, ito]` make more sense?